# Angular with Server sent event

Tags: angular

How can i use server sent event with angular 6. I need to be getting data from backend periodically.  I used it the normal way but it's not working

```
this.source=EventSource(url);
```

this.source.onmessage=(event) =>alert(event.data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instantiate the `this.source` object with a new EventSource like this:

```
this.source = new EventSource(url);
```

You can also add an event listener for messages that come in from your backend like this:

```
this.source.addEventListener('message', message => { alert(message.data); });
```

Use the network tab within your browser's developer tools to ensure that the connection to the SSE is established and that messages are being received by the client.

Comment: i have done everything as you just type but the following is what i got from the console    "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection."

Comment: Right, the server should be responding with a MIME type of "text/event-stream". This is most likely an issue on the server side. Take a look at this if you created your server using PHP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Sending_events_from_the_server